# How to Access or recover files from Apple hdd with bad S.M.A.R.T. and 05-reallocating sector bad?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a Macintosh HD (hfsPlus)

```
`[/dev/sdc2 on /media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD type hfsplus(ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)]
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted. `

`Disk /dev/sdc: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000`

`Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  1465149167   732574583+  ee  GPT Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.`
`
```

Diagnostic software tells me that the S.M.A.R.T. status is bad and also that the 05-reallocating sector count is bad.

I'm trying to recover some data from it without having to spend $600 to ship it to a company that does the manual recover. I don't care about the disk, it's still under warranty. I tried to go to mac doctor but they couldn't get anything out (I think they just tried mounted it on a mac and runitf MacDrive.)

I've tried with Windows 7 and I managed to mount the drive but some software was not seeing it and the only one who did it was too slow and kind of crappy. I'm trying now with Ubuntu in a bootable flashdrive but I cannot open the media because of input/output errors while reading the .journal file.
Mounting the drive with the system gives this windows message:

`

```
 Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD:
 Command-line mount  -t "hfsplus" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc2"  "/media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,missing  codepage or helper program, or other error.In some cases useful info is  found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so`
```

I'm addressing this issue with different methods, too long to be listed all, but I' trying every pieace of information I`m finding so far. I'd love it if someone could point me in the right direction; I have some fundamental knowledge on computers but I'm not a developer, and recently got into ubuntu just as one alternative.